# How do you subtract a value from a counter in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods

Say that `length=11` and that I want to subtract `2` from it on every cycle until it reaches `1`. Is my code for the `for` method correct? And what would it be for a `while` loop?

```
for(int i =length ; i!=1; i-=2)
```

EDIT: This was the question. To solve it I made an if statement that if the length%2==1 I would use the for loop listed above. Then I am going to write an else stating modifying the code above to stop at 0. Does this make sense?

The sum of all digits at odd positions (right-to-left starting at 1 as the right-most digit) of a numeric input. (For example, if the input is 432677, the sum would be 7 + 6 + 3 = 16.)

Comment: I might be tempted to use `i >= 1` instead of `i != 1`

Comment: This is because if length is even i could "miss" 1 and continue down the negative numbers forever

Answer (score 4):

1. For is not a method. It's a language construct. Just a nitpick.
2. Almost. If `i` starts out even you'll never end. Use:

   ```
   for(int i =length ; i>1; i-=2)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If the 1 is inclusive, you could try:

```
for(int i = length; i >= 1; i -= 2){ ... }
```

Or

```
for(int i = length; i > 0; i -= 2){ ... }
```

If the 1 is exclusive, you could try:

```
for(int i = length; i > 1; i -= 2){ ... }
```

Comment: No, no, no. 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, ***1***.

Comment: -Reasoning is incorrect, but the code is close/right. "reaches" is going to end up being the keyword-

Comment: My bad, long day at college :(

Comment: @JoshM Perfectly understood, I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: Second little nitpick. `i >= 1` is not the same stopping condition as the OP wanted as they used `i != 1`.

Comment: @hexafraction Glad you can understand :) Taking an advanced software development course isn't exactly the *lightest* program. And I was unsure if the 1 was inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: Sounds like from the use case we can deduce that it's supposed to be inclusive, but the original for loop excluded 1.

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes, it did exclude 1, but I believe the OP was unsure that it did. The way the question was phrased: *when it reaches 1* you can't really assume that it means that the 1 is exclusive.